# Use regex to extract a chunk a table, then an array of rows

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to use regex in javascript to scrape some information from a website. At the moment, I have two separate matching patterns. The first extracts a table ...

```
/(?:<tbody>)(.*?)(?:<\/tbody>)/
```

whilst the second splits the returned content into rows...

```
/(?:<tr>)(.*?)(?:<\/tr>)/g
```

... now I was wondering if I could do this in one 'move', as it were. I want it to be ...

```
(?:<tbody>)((?:<tr>)(.*?)(?:<\/tr>))(?:<\/tbody>)/g
```

but no joy. Of course, I *could* use the .split method, but this doesn't fit with my broader process - I have an array of regex's which are foreach'd to extract the info I need.

Any help, much appreciated...

Comment: you could also use a DOM manipulator.

Comment: You shouldn't try using a regex to parse html see here for details:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not

Answer (score 1):

Parse the string containing the HTML, for example, using jQuery:

```
var html = '<table><tbody><tr><td>row 1</td></tr><tr><td>row 2</td></tr></tbody></table>';    
var dom = $.parseHTML(html);    
var rows = $(dom).find('tr');
console.log(rows);
```

Output:

```
Object[tr, tr]
```

If you want to access the HTML as a string, you can use `.outerHTML`, for example:

```
$.each(rows, function (i, el) {
    console.log(el.outerHTML);
});
```

Output:

```
<tr><td>row 1</td></tr>
<tr><td>row 2</td></tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can do it by using a single regex: `/(<tbody>|<\/tbody>|<tr>.*?<\/tr>)/g`.**

### Here it is:

```
text = '<tbody><tr><td>sample</td></tr><tr><td>sample2</td></tr></tbody>';
exp = /(<tbody>|<\/tbody>|<tr>.*?<\/tr>)/g;

array = text.match(exp);

> ["<tbody>", "<tr><td>sample</td></tr>", "<tr><td>sample2</td></tr>", "</tbody>"]
```

Then the first element of the array will be `<tbody>`, the last one will be `</tbody>`, and any other element will be a line of the table, like this:

```
> ["<tbody>", line1, line2, line3, ..., line n, "</tbody>"]
```

**So you can do this to obtain only the lines:**

```
text = '<tbody><tr><td>sample</td></tr><tr><td>sample2</td></tr></tbody>';
exp = /(<tr>.*?<\/tr>)/g;

lines = text.match(exp);

> ["<tr><td>sample</td></tr>", "<tr><td>sample2</td></tr>"]
```